# I need advice with error handling for multiple unique columns

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nestJS + typeorm + postgres database

I'm setting up an authentication system and want to have username AND email unique. I want to response to the user an error which of both is taken if he enters dublicates for the database. For one unique column it would be easy, but I have two.

If I try to insert dublicates for both username and email, i get only an error for username, because it skipps the email:

I could check for existing entries in database, but that would be one or two extra database calls and would be my last plan, if there is no other possibility.

My Entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @Unique('Dublicate name', ['name'])
    username: string;

    @Column()
    @Unique('Dublicate email', ['email'])
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;
}
```

My Repository:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
    async signUp(signUpCrendentialsDto: SignUpCrendentialsDto): Promise<void> {
        const { username, password, email } = signUpCrendentialsDto;

        const user = new User();
        user.username = username;
        user.password = password;
        user.email = email;

        try{
            await user.save();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
    [0] { QueryFailedError: doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »UQ_78a916df40e02a9deb1c4b75edb«
    [0]     at new QueryFailedError (E:\repositories\duckwars_backend\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    [0]     at Query.<anonymous> (E:\repositories\duckwars_backend\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    [0]     at Query.handleError (E:\repositories\duckwars_backend\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:142:17)
    [0]     at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (E:\repositories\duckwars_backend\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:194:17)
    [0]     at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    [0]     at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\repositories\duckwars_backend\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:126:12)
    [0]     at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    [0]     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    [0]     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    [0]     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    [0]   message:
    [0]    'doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »UQ_78a916df40e02a9deb1c4b75edb«',
    [0]   name: 'QueryFailedError',
    [0]   length: 323,
    [0]   severity: 'FEHLER',
    [0]   code: '23505',
    [0]   detail: 'Schlüssel »(username)=(Nutzername)« existiert bereits.',
    [0]   hint: undefined,
    [0]   position: undefined,
    [0]   internalPosition: undefined,
    [0]   internalQuery: undefined,
    [0]   where: undefined,
    [0]   schema: 'public',
    [0]   table: 'user',
    [0]   column: undefined,
    [0]   dataType: undefined,
    [0]   constraint: 'UQ_78a916df40e02a9deb1c4b75edb',
    [0]   file:
    [0]    'd:\\pginstaller.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\access\\nbtree\\nbtinsert.c',
    [0]   line: '534',
    [0]   routine: '_bt_check_unique',
    [0]   query:
    [0]    'INSERT INTO "user"("username", "email", "password") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"',
    [0]   parameters: [ 'Nutzername', 'ich.kann@mich.reg', 'hAllo12345' ] }
```

Is there some way for a good solution without the extra database call(s)?

Comment: You cannot validate multiple columns as unique in a single insert - unless all are if unique. . SQL uses AND conditions and short circuit evaluation: once any predicate evaluates FALSE others are not evaluated; regardless of their true/false condition it cannot change the true/false condition of the statement as a whole. SQL only cares about the statement as a whole not individual predicates.

Comment: However you can avoid multiple trips to the server in the vast majority of cases - DO not check before inserting. Determine the overall results in your error handling routine. 
The error message indicates which column failed the unique check. Use that and then SELECT the other from the data base. That way you only make 1 extra server call and only when you already know that as a whole the statement fails and none when it's successful. Hopefully that's  the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I will do that =)

Comment: You are welcome. It's one of my long time premises: Assume your data is good and works properly, write code for when that fails. Rather than the opposite: Assume the data is not good write code to make sure it is. You'll wind up writing the error handling code anyway. Good luck.